# How to delelte last string into a big string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, join, split

I have a big string like this

```
Data-Example - Details -2 - production

Data-Example 2-Details-3 - performance
```

I want to create a function to split my string and return the same string but without the last flag, for example for the fist string the output should look like :

```
Data-Example - Details -2
```

And the other string should look like :

```
Data-Example 2-Details-3
```

I'm trying to split and join the inputs but i'm lost, have you an idea please how to achieve it ?
thank you

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: you must first use a variable to work your string entities, otherwise nothing can be possible.

Comment: It looks like `lastIndexOf('-')` might be a good place to start.  Also `.trim()` is useful to trim the first part before the `-`.  Regular expressions are also useful in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that, you'll have to get the index of the last appearance of "-", which will mark the start of the last flag. Then, extract the string until the found index. Finally, trim the additional white spaces (This can be omitted).

```
let x = "Data-Example - Details -2 - production"
x.substring(0, x.lastIndexOf("-")).trim()
```